# Comparing two dictionaries for specific value within list of dict

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have two list of dictionaries. I am looping through them and looking for matching id. If the id in the src_dict matches to destination I need to call an update method else an insert method. When I am using the below code I am getting unintended result.

This  is the outcome I want. While updating i need to preserve rec_id from dest dict with corresponding values from src dict. insert is pretty much just the src dict elements thats not in dest dict. Appreciate any help!

```
records_update = [{'rec_id': 'abc', 'fields': {'id': 111, 'name': 'sam'}}, {'rec_id': 'xyz', 'fields': {'id': 333, 'name': 'name_changed_to_not_ross'}}]
#. the rec_id is from dest_dict while rest of the field should come from src_dict since these values could change that needs to be update
```

```
records_insert = [{"id": 444, "name": "jack"}]
```

````
src_dict = [{"id": 111, "name": "sam"}, {"id": 333, "name": "name_changed_to_not_ross"}, {"id": 444, "name": "jack"}]

dest_dict = [{"rec_id":"abc","fields":{"id":111,"name":"sam"}}, 
                {"rec_id":"pqr","fields":{"id":222,"name":"john"}},
                 {"rec_id":"xyz","fields":{"id":333,"name":"ross"}}]


records_update = []
records_insert = []
for rec_src in src_dict:
        for rec_dest in dest_dict:
            if rec_src['id'] == rec_dest['fields']['id']:
                print('match and add this element to update list')
                records_update.append(rec_src)
            else:
                print('no match add this element to insert list')
                records_insert.append(rec_src)```
````

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am able to achieve the desired result using this:

```
records_update = []
records_insert = []
for rec_src in src_dict:
    flag = 0
    for rec_dest in dest_dict:
        if rec_src['id'] == rec_dest['fields']['id']:
            new_dict = {}
            print('match and add this element to update list')
            new_dict['rec_id'] = rec_dest['rec_id']
            new_dict['fields'] = rec_src
            records_update.append(new_dict)
            flag = 1
    if flag != 1:
        print('no match add this element to insert list')
        records_insert.append(rec_src)
```

```
records_update
[{'rec_id': 'abc', 'fields': {'id': 111, 'name': 'sam'}},
 {'rec_id': 'xyz', 'fields': {'id': 333, 'name': 'name_changed_to_not_ross'}}]
```

```
records_insert
[{'id': 444, 'name': 'jack'}]
```

Just curious how I can achieve the result using @blhsing approach since that seems to be more efficient approach

```
ids = {d['fields']['id'] for d in dest_dict}
records_update = [dest[d['id']] for d in src_dict if d['id'] in dest]
records_insert = [d for d in src_dict if d['id'] not in dest]
```

Answer (score 2):

You can create a dict indexed by IDs from `dest_dict` for efficient lookups, and then use list comprehensions to filter `src_dict` for respective records:

```
dest = {d['fields']['id']: d for d in dest_dict}
records_update = [dest[d['id']] for d in src_dict if d['id'] in dest]
records_insert = [d for d in src_dict if d['id'] not in dest]
```

Comment: Thanks is there a way to construct the update list like this records_update =:[{'rec_id': 'abc', 'fields': {'id': 111, 'name': 'sam'}, {'rec_id': 'xyz', 'fields': {'id': 333, 'name': 'ross'}}} that way I don't loose the rec_id from dest dict

Answer (score 0):

You need to do an append to insert list only when no append is done to update list.

```
records_update = []
records_insert = []
for rec_src in src_dict:
    flag = 0
    for rec_dest in dest_dict:
        if rec_src['id'] == rec_dest['fields']['id']:
            print('match and add this element to update list')
            records_update.append(rec_dest)
            flag = 1
    if flag != 1:
        print('no match add this element to insert list')
        records_insert.append(rec_src)

print(records_update)
# [{'rec_id': 'abc', 'fields': {'id': 111, 'name': 'sam'}}, {'rec_id': 'xyz', 'fields': {'id': 333, 'name': 'ross'}}]
print(records_insert)
# [{'id': 444, 'name': 'jack'}]
```

Comment: Thanks is there a way to construct the update list like this:[{'rec_id': 'abc', 'fields': {'id': 111, 'name': 'sam'}, {'rec_id': 'xyz', 'fields': {'id': 333, 'name': 'ross'}}} that way I don't loose the rec_id from dest dict

Comment: @DaKuang, yes. Replace the `append` line with `records_update.append(rec_dest)`.

Comment: Thanks I updated my question actually I need only the rec_id from the dest but rest of the fields in the fields key should come from. source since it could change.